# Delaying Render React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and JS and am running into an issue. I want to display a Modal after the user has been on the website for 5 seconds. I am trying to use the "setTimeout" function to delay the render of my Modal. I'm not sure why this is not working. Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Team from '../../images/Team.svg'

import { Button, Background, ModalWrapper, ModalImg, ModalContent, CloseModalButton } from './ModalElements'

const Modal = () => {

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            {showModal ? (
                <Background>
                    <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
                        <ModalImg src={Team} alt="team" />
                        <ModalContent>
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Subtitle thing</p>
                            <button>Join Today</button>
                        </ModalContent>
                        <CloseModalButton aria-label='Close modal' onClick={() => setShowModal(prev => !prev)} />
                    </ModalWrapper>
                </Background>
            ) : null}
        </>
    )
}

class ShowModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timePassed: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ timePassed: true }) }, 5000);
        if (!this.state.timePassed) {
            return Modal
        }
    }
}

export default Modal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Team from '../../images/Team.svg'

import { Button, Background, ModalWrapper, ModalImg, ModalContent, CloseModalButton } from './ModalElements'

const Modal = () => {

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => setShowModal(true), 5000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {showModal ? (
                <Background>
                    <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
                        <ModalImg src={Team} alt="team" />
                        <ModalContent>
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Subtitle thing</p>
                            <button>Join Today</button>
                        </ModalContent>
                        <CloseModalButton aria-label='Close modal' onClick={() => setShowModal(prev => !prev)} />
                    </ModalWrapper>
                </Background>
            ) : null}
        </>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

How it works? [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

You ccan try this approach. With the setTimeout set the state of show modal time passed. and simply use && in render to show the modal when time is passed.

import styled from "styled-components"
import Team from "../../images/Team.svg"

```
import {
    Button,
    Background,
    ModalWrapper,
    ModalImg,
    ModalContent,
    CloseModalButton,
} from "./ModalElements"

const Modal = () => {}

    return (
        <>
                <Background>
                    <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
                        <ModalImg src={Team} alt='team' />
                        <ModalContent>
                            <h1>Title</h1>
                            <p>Subtitle thing</p>
                            <button>Join Today</button>
                        </ModalContent>
                        <CloseModalButton
                            aria-label='Close modal'
                            onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}
                        />
                    </ModalWrapper>
                </Background>
        </>
    )
}

class ShowModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            timePassed: false,
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ timePassed: true })
        }, 5000)
    },[])
    render() {

            return <>
            {this.state.timePassed && (

                <Modal />

            )}
            </>
    }
}

export default Modal
```